# Basic Regular expression not working properly

Tags: regex

I need to match an input on a rails form in the format that it should be 4-digit, and it should not contain 0. Also the numbers in each place(units, tens..) has a maximum limit. I tried `/[1-4[1-7][1-6][1-8]{4}/` but this does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: {n} tells the previous item (and only that one) must appear exactly n times.

Comment: thanks for the insight, but still does not fix it. any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should correct your regexp to match a 4-digit string. Each `[]` character class represents a digit. Since you have 4 classes and the string is only 4 digits long, there's no need for the `{4}` to indicate digits.

A string containing 4 digits surrounded by boundary characters:

```
/\b[1-4][1-7][1-6][1-8]\b/
```

Comment: You can limit this by matching the entire string using `^` and `$` for beginning and end of string respectively or if you are matching within a string you can use boundary characters, `\b`, on either end.

Comment: That works! Although I do not know what else it contained because I defined it exactly as I wrote here.

Comment: No not the ^ and $ signs. I had tried that and it  triggered an error in rails. /b gives me what I want.